# Efficiently sum entire rows which are related through a different matrix

Tags: r, optimization, apply

The goal of my code is to make a new matrix `BySite` which rows are sums of `LOLZ` rows (I am using `colSums()`), which are related in the `XY` matrix. So if two `XY` rows are matching then I want the new matrix to have one row, which sums the related (according to `XY`) `LOLZ` rows.

```
BySite<-matrix(0,dim(unique(XY))[1],dim(LOLZ)[2]);
BySite[1,]<-LOLZ[1,];
for (i in 1:dim(unique(XY))[1]){
  tree<-which(apply(XY, 1, function(x) all(x == unique(XY)[i,]))==TRUE)
  if (length(tree)==1){
    BySite[i,]<-LOLZ[tree,]
  }
  else {
    BySite[i,]<-colSums(LOLZ[tree,])
  }
cat(i," *sigh*")
}
```

`XY` is a latitude and longitude matrix so one could use:

```
XY<-matrix(c(rep(c(55:74),100),rep(c(101:120),100)),2000,2)
```

And for LOLZ

```
 LOLZ<-matrix(abs(rnorm(2000*50)),2000,50)
```

My code works but is painfully slow, looking for pieces of advice to make it faster.

Comment: Could you provide smaller "XY" and "LOLZ" matrices with the desired output? If you'll use `runif/sample` etc., it, also, might be better to add a `set.seed` at the beginning, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an attempt with a smaller dataset:

```
XY = cbind(rep(50:55, 3), rep(100:105, 3))
set.seed(007); LOLZ = matrix(sample(1:5, 18 * 5, T), 18, 5)

paste_XY = paste(XY[, 1], XY[, 2], sep = "; ") #or apply(XY, 1, paste, collapse = "; ")
ans = rowsum(LOLZ, paste_XY)

#after running your code to build "BySite"
sum(ans != BySite)
#[1] 0
```